# Log4j + OpenJPA = NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/AttributeConverter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, logging, log4j

I'm trying to get log4j (I would also be happy to use any logging api as log as it is jpa persistent) use jpa appender.

My persistence.xml looks like this

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.jpa.JpaTraceEventMessage</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextMapAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextMapJsonAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextStackAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextStackJsonAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.MarkerAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.MessageAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.StackTraceElementAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ThrowableAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>com.xxxxxx.lab.logging.ReportEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary"/>
        <!-- value="buildSchema" to runtime forward map the DDL SQL; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>
        <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

As per apidocs:

> Many of the return types of LogEvent methods (e.g., StackTraceElement,
>   Message, Marker, Throwable, ThreadContext.ContextStack, and
>   Map) will not be recognized by the JPA provider. In
>   conjunction with @Convert, you can use the converters in the
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter package to
>   convert these types to database columns.

So I added all necessary classes, but it still throws:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/AttributeConverter
```

Comment: Are you using any converters?

Comment: Which is the JPA version you are using? Is it JPA 2.1?

Comment: org.apache.openjpa v2.2.2. So far I have merely persistance configuration (as shown) and one Entity class ReportEntity extending  BasicLogEventEntity with no explicity convertation

Answer (score 3):

AttributeConverter seems something new in JPA2.1.  Are you sure your project is using JPA2.1 instead of any prior version?

Just curious, why are you so insists to use JPA for log persistence?  There are plenty JDBC-based solution which works well.  I don't see any reason for using JPA solution unless you are going to make use of the logging related entities in your application.

Comment: org.apache.openjpa v2.2.2.because my entire project is under JPA, I would love to have may be an editional persistance unit for logging perposes.

Comment: From the homepage of Apache OpenJPA, OpenJPA 2.2.2 is a "compliant implementation of the JSR-317 Java Persistence 2.0 specification".  So it is not compliant to JPA 2.1 I believe.  And, though your project is under JPA, if you are not going to make use of the logging related entites in your project, there is still meaningless to make use of JPA persistence for log (in fact it is a bad choice I will say, because of all the extra overheads)